# Proving general axioms of the translation mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

From S.L Linear Algebra:

> Let  $V$ be a vector space, and let $u$ be a fixed element of $V$. We
>   let $T_u: V \rightarrow V$ be a map such that $T_{u}(v)=u+v$. We call
>   $T_{u}$ a translation  by $u$.
>
> If $S$ is any subset of $V$, then $T{u}(S)$ is called translation of
>   $S$ by $u$, and consists of all vectors $u$+$v$, with $v \in S$. We
>   often denote it by $S+u$. In the picture below, we draw a set $S$ and
>   its translation by a vector $u$. [image]
>
> Prove that if $u_1$, $u_2$ are elements of $V$, then
>   $T_{u_1+u_2}:T_{u_1} \circ T_{u_2}$. Also, prove that if $u$ is an
>   element of $V$, then $T_{u}:V \rightarrow V$ has an inverse mapping
>   which is nothing but translation $T_{-u}$.

**Note**:

"$\circ$" symbol in the text above denotes composite mapping.

## Solutions

**Axiom N1**: *Prove that if $u_1$, $u_2$ are elements of $V$, then $T_{u_1+u_2}:T_{u_1} \circ T_{u_2}$.*

**Proof:**

Let $S$ be a subset of $V$, then $T_{u_1+u_2}(S)=\{v+(u_{1}+u_{2}) \mid v \in S \}$ which is equal to $T_{u_1} \circ T_{u_2}(S)=T_{u_1}(T_{u_2}(S))=\{(v+u_{2})+u_{1} \mid v \in S\}$ due to the commutativity and associativity axioms declared in vector spaces.

---

**Axiom N2**: *Also, prove that if $u$ is an element of $V$, then $T_{u}:V \rightarrow V$ has an inverse mapping which is nothing but translation $T_{-u}$.*

**Proof**:

Let $S$ be a subset of $V$, then $T_u(S)=\{v+u \mid v \in S\}$. Inverse mapping of $T_{u}(S)$ then must be a function $L$ such that $L_{t}(T_{u}(S))=I=0$ where $I$ is additive identity. This is only possible if $t=-u$.

---

Are both proofs valid? I'm slightly worried that they might have few mistakes in them. Perhaps there are even better ways to prove it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to work with *elements* of $V$, instead of *subsets*. Asserting that $T_{u_1+u_2}=T_{u_1}\circ T_{u_2}$ means that, for each $v\in V$,$$T_{u_1+u_2}(v)=T_1\bigl(T_{u_2}(v)\bigr),$$which is easy:\begin{align}T_{u_1+u_2}(v)&=(u_1+u_2)+v\\&=u_1+(u_2+v)\\&=T_1\bigl(T_{u_2}(v)\bigr).\end{align}The same objection applies to the other proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I may ask, utilization of elements of the vector space are definitely more appropriate, but was my proof above invalid due to subsets or just negligible?

Comment: @ShellRox What you proved is correct and, from what you did, you can deduce what I proved; just apply it to subsets with a single element.